# Chrome & Firefox not rendering huge stylesheet (>200k characters) while Safari works fine

Tags: css, browser, sass, cross-browser

we're stuck at a strange behavior in a clients project:

We have many SCSS files resulting in a compiled CSS file of 240000 characters in size.

I was able to develop in Safari without a problem.
Then a colleague started working on the same project using Chrome - he got a completely unstyled page. In Firefox he got the same problem. I tried it with Chrome and Firefox on the Mac too, and yep - they both won't display the page anymore.

"Anymore" because it worked fine. The only thing that changed is the SASS compilation workflow to use the Wordpress Plugin "WP-SCSS" instead of Grunt.

Our new compiled CSS seems to be bigger than the previous one. Maybe the underlying Foundation framework was customized, so that it did not include that many rules. Anyway: more rules should not end up in a broken stylesheet like in IE some years ago. Therefore Safari (both v9.1 and "Safari Technology Preview") render fine.

Yes, all browsers are up to date.

Yes, all caches are cleared.

Has anyone an idea, a hint, or a guess?

Comment: Remove half of the stylesheet. Does it work? Then undo, keep that half and remove a half of the remaining. Otherwise, remove half of the remaining. Repeat (binary search).

Comment: Solved it by using the Compass App instead of WP-SCSS (based on scssphp). I'm going to do some research on the differences of both compiled files.